# Using custom AngularJS directives and routing with ExpressJS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I created an AngularJS app, and using this tutorial (https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial), have been trying to create an ExpressJS/Node backend to go with it. Unfortunately, this tutorial is written around a single view with a single controller, whereas my AngularJS app has multiple custom directives.

So, at this step in the above tutorial (**Importing Our Angular Project**), my app stops working. I'm not sure why and several days of Googling and tinkering have not solved this issue.

I've found other tutorials, but they don't answer this situation (again, there's that single-page-without-anything-complicated-like-directives assumption), and I don't have enough experience yet to understand the ExpressJS Docs.

Specifically, I created the ExpressJS app using these steps from the tutorial (in Ubuntu):

1. npm install -g express-generator
2. express --ejs nameOfApp
3. cd nameOfApp
4. npm install
5. npm install --save mongoose

I then moved both my HTML views (converted to ejs files) and Angular JS files into it, but now get this error when I run `npm start` and type "http : // localhost : 3000" into my browser.

The index.ejs file needs two additional views (in the form of AngularJS modules): the `nav-view . ejs` and `update-view . ejs`. They’re no longer getting found or loaded. From my node.js terminal, it's giving me 404 errors for both these.

I am certain it’s something simple I’m overlooking, probably involving the app.js or index.js files, but I have no idea what that is.

Below are snippets from my code and the error; please let me know if more information is needed.

1) I have defined custom directives and views so that the index.ejs file includes both an insert point for the current state, as well as an omnipresent navigation bar:

```
...
<!-- Templates are inserted in below tag per state machine -->
<div ui-view></div>
<!--  navigation bar is always visible -->
<nav-view></nav-view>
</body>
…
```

2) My AngularJS app (main.js) uses the below controller and directives. **I have tinkered a lot with the templateUrl but have not gotten a solution that way.**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var pageApp = angular.module('page', ['routes']);

     pageApp.controller('UpdateCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'updateFactory', function($scope, $http, updateFactory) {

        $scope.updates = updateFactory.updates;
        ... 

    }]); //end of the UpdateCtrl controller

    //below is the directive for the navigation bar
    pageApp.directive('navView', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E'
            , templateUrl: 'views/nav-view.ejs'
            , controllerAs: 'navCtrl'
        };
    });

    //below is the directive for a list of updates that are inserted into the index view upon loading
    pageApp.directive('updateView', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E'
            , templateUrl: 'views/update-view.ejs'
            , controllerAs: 'updateCtrl'
            , controller: 'UpdateCtrl'
            , bindToController: true
        };
    });

 .…
```

3) The below snippet is from my `_AngularJS_` routing file, where I set up the states. Note that the "list of updates" view should be loaded in the initial state:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var pageApp = angular.module('routes', ['ui.router']);

    pageApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('homeState', {
            url: '/home'
            , template: '<update-view>'
        })
        .state('blogState', {
        …
```

4) Below, for reference, is the app.js file auto-generated by Express. I have not touched it except to uncomment the favicon code afer moving the icon to the proper location.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

5) Below is index.js, which is also automatically generated by ExpressJS. I believe the solution involves either adding something here, or creating more files like it.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET needed pages. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Index' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for any help. I have relatively complex AngularJS code, but the tutorials all use really simple examples and insufficient resources for closing that gap.

Comment: place your templates inside public folder and change templateUrl accordingly in the directives

Comment: if by "accordingly" you mean "views/name.ejs," it's not working; also, an explanation of why/how ExpressJs looks in different folders, and its base search point, is necessary

Comment: You need to place templates in public folder because then only they can be served and be accessible at client side from you directives.

Comment: app.use(express.static(...)) is meant to serve such files like css,js required at the client

Answer (score 0):

Anmol Mittal had the right idea:

The templates do have to be located in the public folder, but **not the index template**, which needs to be located in the views folder - if you move all the templates, Express won't have anything to load.

In this particular setup, Express loads the index, and the index in turn serves the other templates.

Comment: index.ejs doesnt actually counts in template because its your basic/main file.Your templates are update-view.ejs , etc.